# Tomcat8.0.50のerror-pageの設定について

Tags: tomcat

Tomcat8.0.50の web.xml に以下の記述を記述しているのですが、指定した error.jsp を読まずにデフォルトのエラーページ(HTTPステータス 500)が表示されます。

なお、Tomcat5.5で実施した時は、
以下の記述で error.jsp を表示する事が出来ました。

どのようにしたら error.jsp を表示する事が、
出来るのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```xml
<error-page>
<error-code>500</error-code>
<location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: 「Tomcat8.0.50のwem.xml」というのは`conf/web.xml`のことですか？

Comment: はい。conf/web.xmlになります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

アプリケーション固有のエラーページを定義したいのであれば、アプリケーション内の`WEB-INF/web.xml`に`<error-page>`を定義してみて下さい。

`conf/web.xml`に以下のような定義をした場合、これはすべてのアプリケーションに適用されるグローバルなエラーページの設定になります。

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

あるアプリケーションでシステムエラー（HTTP 500エラー）が発生したときに、そのアプリケーション固有の`WEB-INF/web.xml`に`<error-page>`の定義があれば、それが適用されますが、無ければ、上記のグローバルな`<error-page>`の定義が適用されます。

例えば、webappsにexamplesというアプリケーションがあり、このアプリケーション内でシステムエラーが発生した場合を考えます。

`webapps/examples/WEB-INF/web.xml`に以下の`<error-page>`の定義があれば、`webapps/examples/examples_error.jsp`が適用されますが、この定義が無ければ、グローバルの定義が効いて`webapps/examples/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp`が適用されます。

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/examples_error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

ちなみに、

> なお、Tomcat5.5で実施した時は、
>   以下の記述で error.jsp を表示する事が出来ました。

は、Tomcatのバージョンによる動作の違いではないと思います。

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。ご連絡頂きました内容で設定したエラーページは表示されました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @waku123 解決したら、[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)しておいて下さい。